# iOS 8 textDocumentProxy - able to delete more than one space?

Tags: ios, ios8, textdocumentproxy

I would like to delete multiple spaces from `self.textDocumentProxy` when working with my extension's `KeyboardViewController`, and was wondering if there is a Apple-supported method that specifically performs this action?

So far, I have been using a pretty "hacky" way of doing the following (here it deletes all the previous characters found on `textDocumentProxy`):

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput.length; i++){
        [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
    }
```

The issue with this lies in the method `deleteBackward`, which, depending on what prompt is given, always deletes around half (its quite reliable, especially when `documentContextBeforeInput` is longer than 20 characters) of the total number of times its told to delete. Since this is rather unreliable, I was wondering if there is a way to easily delete multiple spaces, or all of the texted in `textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput`

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fundamental issue in the loop you're using:

```
for (int i = 0; i < self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput.length; i++){
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
```

The `i < self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput.length` check is performed multiple times. And the `.length` attribute is actually decreasing by 1 for every `deleteBackward` you do. `i` however is merrily increasing by 1 for each iteration.

As a result only half will be deleted.

You can flip the order around to fix the issue.

```
for (int i = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput.length; i > 0; i--){
    [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];
}
```

You can also cache the original length of the textDocument before you start changing it.

Comment: Doesn't work with long text. I tried many times with long text but sometimes it didn't clear all the text. Random some text are left

Comment: I tried many times, but with long text, random text still remain. but if i check hasText() will return false. That's really weird, it's seems error of ios

Comment: Well that simply means that there is something else going on. And my experience with iOS has never extended to handling keyboard events or even doing a lot of input handling. So I won't be of much use there.

Comment: i entered only two lines of text (80 characters) but i couldn't complete clear all of it. Random few characters left remain.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this solution that will erase everything in the input text, not only the text before the cursor ;)

```
func deleteInputText() {

    if let afterInput = self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextAfterInput {
        self.textDocumentProxy.adjustTextPositionByCharacterOffset(afterInput.characters.count)
    }
    while let _=self.textDocumentProxy.documentContextBeforeInput {

            self.textDocumentProxy.deleteBackward()


    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
while (self.textDocumentProxy.hasText==YES)
{    
  [self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];      
}
```

should remove all the text.

`[self.textDocumentProxy deleteBackward];` deletes only 1 character.